# jQuery sum of all class text as numbers

Tags: jquery, class, sum, addition

I'm looking to sum up all text as numbers inside the class called "sent" but when I alert the below code it gives output of zero:

```
var sum = 0;            
var thedate = $(".date:contains('15th February 2012')");

   $(thedate).each(function() {              
    var sents = $(this).next('.sent').text();

    var sentsnumb = parseFloat(sents);

        sum += Number($(sentsnumb));

});
    alert(sum);
```

Here is my html:

```
<tr>
   <td class="date">15th February 2012</td>
   <td class="sent"> 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="date">15th February 2012</td>
   <td class="sent"> 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="date">15th February 2012</td>
   <td class="sent"> 10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="date">15th February 2012</td>
   <td class="sent"> 10</td>
</tr>
```

Desired output from above would be the number "30".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
var sum = 0;            
var thedate = $(".date:contains('15th February 2012')");

   $(thedate).each(function() {              
    var sents = $(this).next('.sent').text();
    sum = sum + Number(sents);
});

alert(sum);​
```

Actual problem is with **$(sentsnumb)**. It should be replaced with **sentsnumb**

Comment: This works: See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLDpM/

The reason you need to use the `Number()` function is that `.text()` returns a string of text. `Number()` turns that text back into a numerical value that you can sum up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;             
var thedate = $(".date:contains('15th February 2012')"); 

$(thedate).each(function() {               
   var sents = $(this).next('.sent').text(); 
   var sentsnumb = parseFloat(sents); 
   sum += sentsnumb; 
}); 
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass everything through the jQuery `$` function.

```
var sum = 0;
var thedate = $(".date:contains('15th February 2012')");

thedate.each(function() { // `thedate` is already a jQuery object, no need for `$()`
    var sents = $(this).next('.sent').text();

    var sentsnumb = parseInt(sents, 10); // use parseInt if your values don't have decimals

    sum += sentsnumb; // sentsnum is a float, do not use `$()` (or Number)
});

alert(sum);​
```

Also, you cannot have `<tr>` tags outside of a `<table>`, make sure your HMTL is valid.